# Sequelize - Is bulkCreate() multiple associated object possible with single INSERT?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I'm currently working with Sequelize, and I've run into an issue I can't solve by referencing the docs for Sequelize.

Say I have two associated objects. Person and Pet. A Person has one Pet...

```
Person : {
  name: "personName",
  job: "softwareJob"
  pet: {
    name: "petName",
    age: "dogYears"
  }
}
```

When I try to create an object like this which has an association... 
   `Pet.belongsTo(Person, {source, target})`

via

```
Person.create({
  //person details
  //pet details
},
{
  include: [Pet]
})
```

It creates *two separate* INSERT statements. I'm simply wondering if there's a way to do a **single** INSERT for an associated object. Thanks!

Comment: What are the two inserts? If you're creating a new person and a new pet then that sounds right... please clarify your question if this isn't the case.

Comment: I should have made it more clear. Using an ORM like Hibernate, you can accomplish this INSERT in one statement, rather than through multiple statements. This would be incredibly beneficial for my application due to the high volume. Furthermore, the bulkCreate() method, which created multiple objects in one statement, seems to only allow one object type.

Comment: Last resolve will be writing a raw query http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html.